# Setup Windows7 To accept snmp requests and forward to my own snmp server

Tags: windows-7, snmp, snmpd

I'm a newbie to snmp.
I've written an SNMP server (Based on [this](http://github.com/tcurdt/jmx2snmp) open source code).
I can succesfully send it get request and receive responses with MIBBrowser locally (on localhost)
Next, I tried to connect to it from another PC in the same lan but the SNMP UDP packet never arrives at the server application.

I can see the packet in wireshark on the target Pc but the server application never gets it.

I turned off Windows firewall completely. Tried ports 161, 1161 and 5555 (Both server and MIBBrowser were configured correctly).

I was wondering if any special setup is required for SNMP to work on windows 7 and if there is anything that might be blocking it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work with SNMPD as the host.
The windows service is very difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

How do you have the SNMP service configured on the Windows 7 computer? Is it configured to accept SNMP communications from the test computer? What Community name is configured on the Windows 7 computer and what Community name are you using on the test computer?

Comment: How do I configure the Windows Snmp service to work as a proxy for my own agent?